# How to split string with words, numbers and semicolons to map?

Tags: regex, kotlin

I need to split this string by a semicolon and write to the map with the key word and value number.

```
"Mercedes 2000; BMW 2500; Audi 2000; Porsche 1000"
```

Final output of map should looks like:

```
{Mercedes=2000, BMW=2500, Audi=2000, Porsche=1000}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First split by `";"` and then map:

```
val str = "Mercedes 2000; BMW 2500; Audi 2000; Porsche 1000"
val map = str
        .split(";")
        .map { it.trim().substringBefore(" ") to it.trim().substringAfter(" ") }
        .toMap()
println(map)
```

will print:

```
{Mercedes=2000, BMW=2500, Audi=2000, Porsche=1000}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val input = "Mercedes 2000; BMW 2500; Audi 2000; Porsche 1000"

val map = HashMap<String, String>()
val keyValue = input.split("; ") // split the input into key-value items
for (item in keyValue) {
    val keyValueSplit = item.split(" ")// split the key and the value
    val key = keyValueSplit[0]
    val value = keyValueSplit[1]
    map[key] = value // insert into result map
}
println(map)
```

Output

> {Audi=2000, Porsche=1000, Mercedes=2000, BMW=2500}

Be careful to do the first split at `"; "` with a whitespace. Otherwise the second split at the whitespace`" "` will give you a different result.

Answer (score 1):

As you have specifically asked for a regex solution:

```
val map = HashMap<String, String>()
val regex = """(\S+)\s+(\d+)(?:;\s+)?""".toRegex()
for (m in regex.findAll("Mercedes 2000; BMW 2500; Audi 2000; Porsche 1000"))
    map[m.groupValues[1]] = m.groupValues[2]
println(map)
```

This yields

```
{Audi=2000, Porsche=1000, Mercedes=2000, BMW=2500}
```

Read more about [**Regex in Kotlin here**](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-regular-expressions) and [**see a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/2N28ti/1).